# Dynamic range for Linked Excel Object/range in Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, pivot-table

I have a Excel Pivot table linked my Word report.
The Pivot table will growth when getting more data. However, when the Pivot table size change, it doesn't be reflected in the Word file. The word file always display the original selected range. So I have to update the link range manually.

Is there is a way to fix this issue or simply the effort?

Many thanks.

Comment: I found the same question in this link but the answer doesn't work for me. I can't set the Pivot table as another Excel table again. Does the solution work? Can someone help? I really need this work to integrate with Excel report to word quickly. thank you very much. http://superuser.com/questions/177238/how-to-link-to-an-excel-pivot-table-that-will-expand-over-time-in-word-2007

Comment: Found Workaround: 1. define Named range for Pivot table. 2. Use Offset function to get the Pivot table range.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution to fix this issue.
1. Create a Named Range for the Pivot Table.
2. Change the Linked Range absolute address in Word file to the Named Range

================

Note for 1:
create named range for a Pivot table can be done via Excel "Offset" function. 
However, the Offset function is not perfect when there are more data in the same sheet.
so I create my own Excel function to that.

```
Function PVRange1(Sheet_Name, Pivot_Name) As Range
'Returns a Range object that represents the range containing the entire PivotTable report, but doesn’t include page fields.
'
Dim pvt As PivotTable

Set pvt = Worksheets(Sheet_Name).PivotTables(Pivot_Name)
Set PVRange1 = pvt.TableRange1

End Function


Function PVRange2(Sheet_Name, Pivot_Name) As Range
'Returns a Range object that represents the range containing the entire PivotTable    report, including page fields.

Dim pvt As PivotTable

Set pvt = Worksheets(Sheet_Name).PivotTables(Pivot_Name)
Set PVRange2 = pvt.TableRange2

End Function
```